# my question is about the error when removing " " from a code

Tags: java

```
private void setStudentID(){
        id++;
        this.studentID = gradeYear + "" + id;
    }
```

Why when i remove the quote, "" , it becomes error?
Sorry for interrupting with basic question.

Comment: remove `+ ""` not just `""`

Comment: Please read [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly. Like making it clear what types all these variables have.

Answer (score 1):

I think `gradeYear` and `id` is not a `String` but`this.studentID` is a String. plus the `""` mean you will treat the result `gradeYear + id;` is a `String` (which is correct), remove the `""` will not be correct anymore since number cannot store in a `String`

---

Some test I tried

```
System.out.println(10 + 11);        //21
System.out.println(10 + "" + 11);   //1011
System.out.println(10 + 11 + "");   //21
System.out.println("" + 10 + 11);   //1011
```

Comment: Yes, gradeYear and id is integer type. So, the " " will change them into String?

Comment: @Muhammad Aiman indeed it is. change the result into String, The same when you do a `double + int`(or any operator), the result will change to type double

Comment: Just to get the terminology exact: the `gradeYear + id` expression is int if both vars are `int`; the `gradeYear + "" + id` expression is a String, because Java allows you to concatenate Strings and ints and treats the result as a String. Java does not, however allow you to assign an int to a String variable, so if the expression is in an assignment statement to a String variable, then the expression on the right-hand side must be compatible, and so cannot be an int. Java doesn't change 'them' to an int, it just treats the expression as either an int or a String based on these rules

Answer (score 0):

The `""` forces the concatenation to happen on a `String` (internally it uses `StringBuilder`). So, the better way to write your statement would be

```
this.studentID = new StringBuilder().append(gradeYear).append(id).toString();
```

Comment: Why is that "better"?

Comment: @GhostCat Because it works. The [`String` Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) notes: *The Java language provides special support for the string concatenation operator ( + ), and for conversion of other objects to strings. String concatenation is implemented through the StringBuilder(or StringBuffer) class and its append method.*

Answer (score -1):

```
this.studentID = gradeYear + "" + id;
```

I believe gradeYear is a string and id shown as int..

it should be:

```
this.studentID = gradeYear + "" + id.ToString();
```

or if you want to remove "" then it would be:

```
this.studentID = gradeYear + id.ToString();
```

Comment: There is no `ToString()` method in Java. `toString()` perhaps, but not on an `int`, so you're wrong either way.